# How do I change sub/child divs of a draggable parent div to a different class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

long time reader, first time poster. I'm creating a webpage with JQuery drag and drop div's and wanted to know how one would go about making it so once a draggable div has been dropped on a "droppable" div, not only is the class of the draggable div changed but one of the child div's within the draggable is changed to a different class?

The HTML is basically-

```
<div class="dropbox"></div>
```

and then the JQuery script for this is-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$("#draggable").draggable({
drag: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).removeClass('dropClass');
    }
});
```

then the droppable section is called like so later in the script-

```
$(".dropbox").droppable({
tolerance: 'intersect',
over: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('hoverClass');
},
out: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass');
},
drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('dropClass');
}
});
```

If a child div for draggable has a class called "indicator", is there a way to append the drop: function event to include

```
$('.indicator').removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('setOn');
```

I realize that the first section creates the class that "draggable" which becomes a part of "ui-draggable-dragging". Is there a way of triggering another class "indicator" without an event which I can call when the drop: function is executed?

Hope this makes sense, I haven't been able to find an answer to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript ..

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('dropClass');
        $(this).children('.indicator').removeClass('setOn');
    }
});



$(".dropbox").droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    over: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('hoverClass');
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass');
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hoverClass').addClass('dropClass');
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').children('.indicator').addClass('setOn');
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you ..